# Does html_CodeSniffer plan to be compatible with WCAG 2.1?

Tags: accessibility, wcag

As of right not, I cannot find anything on the web talking about html_CodeSniffer planning to be compatible with WCAG 2.1, only 2.0.

https://squizlabs.github.io/HTML_CodeSniffer/

Does anyone know if there is an intent to release this in the future?

Comment: https://github.com/squizlabs/HTML_CodeSniffer/issues/214

Answer (score 0):

As per the [open issue on their GitHub repository](https://github.com/squizlabs/HTML_CodeSniffer/issues/214), they've scoped out the work but haven't completed the work.

Not sure how much it'll actually help since they note:

> we identified that many of the new criteria for WCAG 2.1 had elements we couldn't detect programatically